# Facebook Test users - Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token

I am trying to test my app by creating some test users on the app developer portal. When i click on the link "switch to" next to a test user, it logs me out of facebook and logs me in as the test user. However i noticed that the access token for the developer user is not invalidated on logout. Isn't the access token supposed to become invalid in the case of logout (which is the case when i actually logout of facebook as a regular user would). Is this a bug or am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that access tokens don't always expire/invalidate as expected, and in a scenario like yours, you will have to manually set the new access token, leaving the old one in limbo somewhere.

```
$facebook->setAccessToken('new_access_token');
```

should be all you need to log the new user into your app assuming you're using the PHP-SDK.

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is that i am caching the access token in a session variable. I check if the access token is valid, if not i re-instantiate the session. Now if the test user logs in from the same browser, it has access to the access token of the previous user since it has not been invalidated

Comment: Instead of just checking access token validity, you could compare `$facebook->getUser();` with `$facebook->api('/me');// get the id`.  ideally these should be the same but if you are truly logged in as the new user and the old token still exists in the persistent session, its possible that the new user id has been set within the facebook object but the access_token/user_id session vars have not yet... So that comparison is worth a shot.  Are you using a framework?

Comment: No i am not using any framework, just the php facebook sdk. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction here. After checking for token validity, I added another check to compare the access token in the session with    $facebook->getAccessToken()    . If not equal, that means the current user has not been authenticated yet.